# Remove an element while iterating over it

Tags: rust

Is there a way to remove an element while iterationg over it? Here is a code example:

```
for particle in &mut particles {

    let mut delete = false;
    // Do stuff...

    if delete {
        // Remove element from particles vector <-- THIS
    }

}
```

I think it's not possible with this *(dirty)* design. What's the common (elegant?) pattern to remove some elements in a vector assuming I need to iterate in order to know what element I need to remove? Feel free to close if duplicate.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You probably want to use [`Vec::retain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain). It allows you to decide for each element whether or not to keep it. So in your case that would look like this:

```
particles.retain(|particle| {
    let delete = {
        // Do stuff ...
    };
    !delete
})
```

You have to return a `bool` from the closure. If you return `true`, the element is not removed; if you return `false`, it is removed.

If you need to somehow compare one element to all other elements in the vector, then `retain()` is not sufficient anymore. For this case, you can find an awesome answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906012/best-way-to-remove-elements-of-vec-depending-on-other-elements-of-the-same-vec).

Comment: This olny works if the items from the vector don't need to be mutated. If mutation is required, then one can use the (currently unstable) Vec::drain_filter method.

Comment: FYI since Rust 1.61, there's a (stable) [Vec::retain_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain_mut) which allows mutating the elements in the Vec while discarding some of them.