# Issues with a second borrow in rust

Tags: rust

I started with Rust recently and I working on small game, unfortunately, I'm having issues on implementing a simple mechanic due an error of multiple mutable borrows, for instance, the following code has an issue with a second mutable borrow

```rust
struct Margin {
    x: f32,
    y: f32, 
    h: f32, 
    w: f32,
}

struct Level {
    margins: Vec<Margin>,
}

impl Level {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Level{
            margins: vec![]
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self) {
        // Add a new margin on each tick
        self.margins.push(Margin {
          x:0., y:0., w:100., h:0.5,
        });

        // Iterate over margins moving each one down a little
        for (i, m) in self.margins.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            m.y += 1.;

            // Remove margins outside of the screen
            if m.y > 640. {
                self.margins.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = Level::new();
    l.update();
}
```

Error

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.margins` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:31:17
   |
26 |         for (i, m) in self.margins.iter_mut().enumerate() {
   |                       -----------------------------------
   |                       |
   |                       first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                       first borrow later used here
...
31 |                 self.margins.remove(i);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the useful method [retain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) on the `Vec` and the code is fixed as follows:

```rust
struct Margin {
    x: f32,
    y: f32, 
    h: f32, 
    w: f32,
}

struct Level {
    margins: Vec<Margin>,
}

impl Level {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Level{
            margins: vec![]
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self) {
        // Add a new margin on each tick
        self.margins.push(Margin {
          x:0., y:0., h:100., w:0.5,
        });

        // Iterate over margins moving each one down a little
        for m in self.margins.iter_mut() {
            m.y += 1.;
        }

        // Retains only the elements where y is lower than 640.
        self.margins.retain(|v| v.y < 640.);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = Level::new();
    l.update();
}
```

Answered based on a previous answer here [Remove an element while iterationg over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033562/remove-an-element-while-iterationg-over-it)